# Can I replace a mechanical doorbell with a digital one?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

In my home, I have a mechanical doorbell chime that I would like to replace with a new digital chime (a chime with features like volume control, different tones, plays through a speaker). Is it possible to easily replace the chime without too much complications? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: US? Europe?  It matters.

Comment: @Harper Ah yes, sorry. US.

Comment: yes, the in-wall wires will work with a new system. You might have to replace two or three items depending on setup, but you shouldn't have to pull wiring.

Comment: I found a digital that used the existing Xformer for my last house and had 2 inputs short chime down stairs button pushed full chime for upstairs, it also had a speaker output so I put one additional speaker downstairs because the unit had a speaker on the chime,,, this was 18 years ago so I am sure there are better ones out there I think it was about 20$ back then. I hope you are talking about the ding ding mechanical door bell that uses power not a twist ring ring bell.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both require the same voltages you will be fine. If you are in the U.S. the line voltage to the transformer is standard house voltage (120 volts AC). The output voltage of the transformer to the chime is nominally 16v.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Even if your current doorbell is totally mechanical, with no electrical power, you can install a digital one by going wireless.  Search the web for "wireless door chime" or "wireless doorbell". They are inexpensive but run on batteries, or pick one up at your local hardware or department store.

Comment: Why would OP want wireless?  I see plenty of wired options although those appear to be best found by searching “door chime with volume control”

Comment: @Tyson OP said he had a mechanical door chime. I took that to mean it was not electrical.  If the OP has power to the door bell, then the wireless option is less important.  Of course, the wireless allows for flexible placement of the chime.

Comment: Even with low voltage wires you have to worry about code. If he runs it off a bluetooth Arduino, or whatever, no code worries. He can even load custom chime sounds.

Comment: I want to stick with my current wired system, so there's not just useless parts hanging around. Also, with a smart doorbell I'm wanting to get with it, it only works with wired systems.